# Are there packages or libraries about sensors,for example laser,to accomplish the simulation?

Tags: simulation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone! I'm trying to describe my question clearly. Now I'm working on a project  based on ros to develop a graphical robot  platform that can simulate behavior of a robot,such as obstacle avoidance,navigation and so on.First I want to solve the simulate question about sensors,because we know that sensors are necessary to avoid obstacle.Are there packages or libraries about sensors,for example laser,which can be useful for me to accomplish the simulation?Or similarly,if you understand what I need,are there any useful links?                                       PS:I have no  physical devices,just want to simulate the behavior.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/155436/are-there-packages-or-libraries-about-sensors,for-example-laser,to-accomplish-the-simulation?/) by [ran95yu](https://answers.ros.org/users/13951/ran95yu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-04-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Charikov](https://answers.ros.org/users/14571/mike-charikov/) on 2014-04-20**:
But ROS is in fact consumer of device data, not provider. You want to simulate something, using ROS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at Gazebo (gazebosim.org), which is an open-source simulator that has ROS integration and plugins for at least simulating laser range finders, cameras, and depth cameras.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0